# Get Started with RxJS in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rxjs

I'm trying to get started with RxJS, but there seems to be a scope issue.

**Error**

```
'Rx' is not defined.
```

---

**main.js**

```
import Rx from 'rx';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRx from 'vue-rx';

Vue.use(VueRouter, Rx, VueRx);
```

**components/App.vue**

```
var dataSource = Rx.Observable ...
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you want: import Observable from 'rxjs'.  then just call Observable...

Comment: `Error: Cannot resolve module 'rxjs'` 

Comment: Do you ever import `Rx` in your `App.vue`?

Answer (score 0):

It was being loaded into the global scope, so I had to use it like this:

```
var dataSource = window.Rx.Observable ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Rx was undefined most likely because you were trying to pull it from the incorrect scope.

It should have been: `import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';`